# How get some parts of a main text (EXCEL VBA)

Tags: vba, text, get, instr

I have a text that is segregated with "/" and I need to get some parts of it.

Operator is my variable that gets the main text from the system.

The text is segregated with "/", so for example I need to get the text between the 2nd and 3rd "/".

Ex1: Main text: 40 XY3131Z/9'6"/ABC/OWN/STL/VENT/8741
column1:ABC

Ex2: Main text: 40 AB/9'6"/ABC/OWN/STL/VENT/8741
column1:ABC

Note: The main text is variable, so I cannot use only = Left or Right
It need to be with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function getText(strTxt As String) As String
    getText = Split(strTxt, "/")(2)
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testGetText()
   Dim x As String
   x = "40 XY3131Z/9'6""/ABC/OWN/STL/VENT/8741" 'the double double quote is to be able to write it in VBA. If the string is in a cell, it may look as you show it...
   MsgBox getText(x)
End Sub
```

Or as UDF (user defined function) from a cell:

```
 =getText(A1)
```

Of course, in A1 should be the text where to extract the string you need...